# Coding Question for SDE Positon - Related to DP

Tags: data-structures, dynamic-programming

My friend gave a test in which he got this question. I tried my best to solve this problem but couldn't get much far,
Can someone provide the approach to solve this question?

Problem statement

[image]

Input?Output Test Cases

[image]

Comment: After being a programmer for 15 years, I can say this company is wasting their time. That's pure garbage for determining if someone is a good developer or not.

Comment: Are you seriously taking pictures of the screen with a camera? Didn't anyone ever tell you about screenshots? Or copy-paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets define a function f(i,j) that gives the maximum value of taken diamonds from the first i boxes (1,2....i) where we picked the diamond j from box i.

Then the answer to your problem will be max(f(n,j)) where j=1,2,...bn where bn is the number of diamonds in box n.

For each box we need to try to pick one diamond and we try to maximize the value with picking one of non similar color diamonds from the previous box, so the formula would be:

```
f(i,j) = Vj + max(f(i-1,k)) // diamond k should not have the same color as diamond j
```

To calculate max(f(i-1,k)) in an efficient way you can keep track of the maximum 2 values of function f(i,j) for each box i:
max1 = f(i,j1)
max2 = f(i,j2)

here is a psuedo code:

```
max1 = -1;
max2 = -1;

for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= diamonds_of_box_i; j++) {
        f[i][j] = -1;
        if (max1.color != diamond[j].color && max1 != -1)
            f[i][j] = max(f[i][j], max1) + Vj;

        if (max2.color != diamond[j].color && max2 != -1)
                f[i][j] = max(f[i][j], max2) + Vj;
        }

        max1 = max2 = -1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= diamonds_of_box_i; j++) {
            if (f[i][j] > max1) {
                max2 = max1;
                max1 = f[i][j];
            }
            else if (f[i][j] > max2) {
                max2 = f[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < diamonds_of_box_n; j++){
        if (f[n][j] > res)
            res = f[n][j];
    }

    print(res);
```

Comment: thanks sir for the solution, but i think this can give tle error considering the constraints given in the question, 
Can we do in this way that we use a dp where we store the value of each functions and if there's already a value for f(i,j1) then just return that

Comment: sorry what do you mean by error? are you referring to time complexity or memory or something else ?

Comment: the time complexity of this solution is O(N+M) and if you use dynamic arrays the memory can also be N+M, and the memory can be decreased further but I don't think you will need it

Comment: if possible can you please elaborate your function more, because it's diffrent than the method given in another answer, and we also have to consider the edge cases also because if it's not possible to pick same color then return -1. Please give some psuedo code for this

Comment: ok, Yes, I went through it, and am only concerned about the time complexity only

Comment: Yes, I need the code, psuedo code will also be great but I need it soon, like in next 45 mins,
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is to determine if a given set of inputs provides any solution at all. One way it would be impossible to have a solution is if two consecutive boxes each only have one color. It uses numbers, but I like to think in colors, so say a box is red, the next box is also red. That's no good, condition fails.

But it gets worse - what if a box is red, the next box is red and orange, and the NEXT box is just orange. Well, if you have to take red in that first box, then you must take orange in the second box. But you also must take orange in the third box!

You start by constructing a matrix of these boxes and keeping track of what gems are inside them, and which of those gems are eligible to be chosen. Iterating over the matrix, you take each box with only one color and exclude the boxes on either side from having that color. Then iterate again, since now some boxes will have only one color now (like the red/orange in the previous example). If you have a box with no valid choices, then you're done. There may be some edge case I'm missing, but hopefully you get the idea now.

This concept is actually very similar to how sudoku solvers work - consider looking at those for inspiration.

If every box has a valid choice, then it's time to optimize for value. I would start by just identifying the largest value diamond in each box. Obviously you want to pick this the most often as possible. A naive algorithm might just iterate over the boxes in a single pass, picking the highest gem, or second highest gem if the highest gem was taken by the last box. A more advanced algorithm might look ahead at the next few boxes (or the entire rest of the set?) to determine which is the best combination. There's probably some more advanced way to handle it that I'm not seeing, but again, this should point some interested party in the right direction.

Comment: i do agree with you that these questions are pretty worthless in determining who is a good developer, but this is a dp problem that can be solved in `O(N)`, you don't need any backtracking style solution. the idea being that the optimal solution for boxes 0 through i can be determined from the optimal solution for boxes 0 through i - 1. the only "state" you care about is which box you're up to and the color of the last diamond, whereas in sudoku you care about every number on the board, which is substantially larger

Comment: @Primusa well you have to be able to look ahead at least `C` boxes to determine if it's possible. C is 1-7 (although if c == 1 and n != 1 then obviously it's not possible hahaha) which isn't far from the 1-9 of sudoku. As far as determining value, you basically described my niave solution - i'm unsure if that is optimal or not, it might be as you say, in which case, cool. OP didn't even know where to start. I think this safely answers where to start.

Comment: Sir, Thanks very much for the explanation , Actually, sir, I have also attached the test cases , can you please take a look through them

Comment: @thebeast I think that goes a bit beyond the scope of what should be going into an answer. If you have a specific question on code you've written, I suggest you isolate that question on its own.

Comment: @Primusa sir, please can you explain a little more about the method you suggested, because I feel that using matrix will give tle error because we have to do in max nLogn i feel, and  another method I am thinking is of using priorityQueue to store diamonds for every box, and take out the one which is not same as previous one, can this work,

Comment: @corsiKa no , I was just asking for approach only, do you think if we have priority Queue for every box , that can help as matrix one will give a time complexity of n^2 i think..